# How to build bottom part of bootstrap nav tab?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

To build nav tabs via Bootstrap, it's simple, I just add code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Tab1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tab2</a></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M4YZ6/

but it's only top part of the tabs, who knows how to build bottom part using bootstrap like on picture below:
[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you need to eiter use jQuery or create other webpages

Comment: See the [documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs). Example of the markup is under the 'Methods' sub-heading.

Answer (score 2):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/M4YZ6/5/

HTML

```
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active">
      <a data-original-title="" rel="tooltip" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-original-title="" rel="tooltip" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a data-original-title="" rel="tooltip" href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Message</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
      Home
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      Profile
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
      Message
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: something like that, but it has breaks, and bottom aren't rouned: http://jsfiddle.net/M4YZ6/7/

Answer (score 1):

I believe Tabbable nav is what you are looking for,

```
<div class="tabbable"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Markup taken from the nav component [documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navs)

===Edit===

[Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M4YZ6/2/)

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui added the fiddle

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't draw bottom part, just same top part as on screenshot

Comment: @ihorko updated the fiddle to incorporate styling for the tabs.

Comment: It doesn't work, you just show another type of tabs, i asked about bottom part

Comment: @ihorko could you define bottom part for me please.